# accessing a column of dataframe after concatenating two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, multiple-columns

I have concatenated two dataframes with below code:

```
df_stacked =pd.concat([df, df_kw], keys=["title","title"],axis= 1,
                  join = "inner").reset_index(drop=True)
```

and it looks like this:

```
df_stacked.iloc[:4,15:18]
```

[image]

How can I take out that upper title value ?
Basically I want to be able to access the budget column by writing:

```
budget = df_stacked.budget
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concatenation has created a two level column names. You can drop the first level (what you call the upper title value) with the function [droplevel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html):

```
df_stacked = df_stacked.droplevel(0, axis=1)
```